# facebook Share image Url along with link in android

Tags: android, image, facebook, url

I want to share image URL along with the link. Previously I used the shareLinkContent for sharing the image and URL but it is not working now.

```
                        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);

                        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()

                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(image)).setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareUrl))

                                .build();
                        shareDialog.show(content);
```

this is my code it shares only content Url not sharing the image Url.Is there any other way to share the link along with the image to the Facebook.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey @gowthami , Did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.b);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    ShareApi.share(content, null);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply.But I want to share both link and image

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links)

> As of April 18, 2017, the following parameters are no longer supported
>   by Graph API versions 2.9 and higher. For versions 2.8 and lower, the
>   parameters will continue working until July 17, 2017.

- contentTitle that represents the title of the content in the link
- imageURL, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post
- contentDescription of the content, usually 2-4 sentences

Comment: can i share two links to the facebook

Comment: @gowthami we can't share multiple links

Comment: then how can I share image along with link . is there any other way to do this.@Vishal

Comment: @gowthami Not possible

Comment: @VishalYadav Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @SudheeshMohan https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links